# Saving to a file actual window name

Tags: c++, winapi

Hello i have simple code which is printing actual window name but i cant save output to the .txt file
code i know wprintf is used to print it on the screen.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

HWND ActualWindow;
fstream LogFile;

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {

        _getch();
        HWND ActualWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
        wchar_t NewName[128];
        GetWindowText(ActualWindow, NewName, 128);
        wprintf(NewName); //Its printing actual window name 

        LogFile.open("dat.txt", fstream::app);
        if (LogFile.is_open()) 
        {
            LogFile << wprintf(NewName); //its saving some numbers 
            LogFile.close();
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `LogFile << NewName;`. Otherwise you're outputting the return value from wprintf.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Of course i was trying it  and im getting something like 716CD4F9300000007

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the return value of `wprintf()`, not printing the content of `NewName`.  You need to replace `LogFile << wprintf(NewName)` with `LogFile << NewName`.

However, then you would be writing a `wchar_t`-based string to a `std::fstream` that expects `char`-based strings, so there is no `operator<<` defined for `wchar_t` strings and you would actually be calling the `operator<<` for `void*` pointers instead (since all pointers are implicitly convertible to `void*`).  As such, you would end up seeing a memory address being printed to the file, not the string content.

Try using `std::wofstream` instead of `std::fstream`, then `LogFile << NewName` should work as expected.

Otherwise, use `GetWindowTextA()` instead, then you can use a `char[]` buffer instead of a `wchar_t[]` buffer, and then your `std::fstream` will work as intended (you will have to replace `wprintf()` with `printf()`, though).